# jsGrid - Get new data when click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

how i can get data row after edit row using jsGrid
my problem : **when i'm click on submit show error message function not exists**

```
<div id="jsGrid"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="funGetNewData();" value="Save" class="btn btn-twitter" />
<script>
    var dataList;
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:50613/Admin/Offers/json_Getdata").done(function (data) {
        dataList = data;
        $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
            width: "100%",

            filtering: true,
            autoload: true,
            inserting: true,
            editing: true,
            sorting: true,
            paging: true,
            pageSize: 5,
            pageButtonCount: 5,
            deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete the client?",

            data: dataList,

            fields: [
                { name: "Name", type: "text", width: 150, validate: "required" },
                { name: "Age", type: "number", width: 50 },
                { type: "control" }
            ]
        });

    });

    function funGetNewData() {
        debugger;
        var dataRow = $("#jsGrid").jsGrid("option", "data")[0];
    };

</script>
```

please help me i need to found any solution about this problem

> thx you UW.

Comment: your question is not clear what exactly you need ? explain more.

Comment: @NarendraJadhav hello, i need to send the final editable data to server, but when i'm save show error message saying : >>  jsGrid function is not exists